# "since you don't tell me anything"/"since you're not telling me anything"?

Tags: word-choice, present-continuous, present-simple

1) I talked to your mom yesterday, since you don't tell me anything.

2) I talked to your mom yesterday, since you're not telling me anything.

Is the first sentence the best choice if I feel that he hasn't shared anything with me over a long time?

And is the sentence natural?

Comment: Do you know the difference between the present simple and present continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first sentence feels better in your context.

**Since you don't tell me anything** feels apt for a situation where it has been like that for a period of time. Example: "It was from your mother that I learnt that you made it to the football team because you don't tell me anything."

**Since you are not telling me anything** feels apt for something that's recent or current and not something that's been ongoing for some time. Example: "You didn't have that bruise before going to John's place. I will call John since you are not telling me anything."

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first sentence is the most appropriate.

The suffix *-ing* would be used if the situation wasn't a habit, and the sentence would be more like "I will talk to your Mom, since you're not telling me anything".

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

“You don’t tell me anything” means “You are in the habit of not giving me information and you are continuing that habit in this case.”

“You aren’t telling anything” means “in this case, you are not giving me information.”

This is the usual distinction between the indicative and the continuous in English.  “You eat meat” means carnivory is your habit or practice, while “you are eating meat” means there is a sausage in your mouth right now.